# SUM of time... how can I get an answer that isn't 00:00:00?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm creating a report for work for monthly stats and, as part of this, I have to calculate the total sign-on time for the team. I have created an individual sheet for each person to sum or average the various different stats.

I've created a table within the sheet and added a Totals Row. I want to SUM the total sign on time. I've set the Totals Row field to SUM, but the answer comes back with 00:00:00. I am copying data from a system generated spreadsheet, but I'm pasting the data as "Value Only", not including the formatting.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or something I'm just not aware of?

When I enter the data manually it gives the correct result, but this is too time consuming to be practical.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Not much context here and is hard to understand your question.

If you paste **values only** of a Time eg 08:30 (Eight and a Half hours), the result is displayed as a decimal like so:

[image]

When you paste your Values in, set the format to "h:mm"

You can then use the SUM function and set the format of the cell as "[h]:mm;@" within custom formatting.

This shows the result as a continuous sum in 24 hour format

see example bellow

[image]

Each Totals formula is the following, only the format changes - "=SUM(Range)"

I hope this helps but without any more context, we cant help.

Thanks